# how to "float" a div down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I understand you can float a div left and right, but why isn't there a property to let you "float" a div up and down? In this case, I'd like to "float" my .imgBtns down, so it is stuck to the bottom of the modal, but cant find a way to achieve this. I've done some research read up on absolute and fixed positions on the divs and messed around with this a little, but still couldn't get it right.

Here's my code.

```css
.contentThree {
  padding-top: 70px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3d3d3d, #191919);
}

.contentThree p {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.photoBG span {
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.faaApproved p {
  color: white;
}

.photoBG {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.paypal {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.paymentBtn1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.imgText {
  color: white;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.button,
select {
  width: 100%;
}

.mDialogPhoto {
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 0px;
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: white;
}

.img-responsiveModal {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.modal-dialog {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog mDialogPhoto" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid parent">
          <div class="col-sm-6 modal3ImgPrev">
            <img class="img-responsiveModal" id="myImg2" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0019-Recovered.jpg' />
          </div>
          <center>
            <form class="paypalForm col-sm-6" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
              <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="NECDG667FLEEY">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Choose Size">Choose Size</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><select name="os0">
                                     <option value="1x1">1x1 $100.00 USD</option>
                                     <option value="2x2">2x2 $200.00 USD</option>
                                     <option value="3x3">3x3 $300.00 USD</option>
                                     <option value="4x4">4x4 $400.00 USD</option>
                                    </select> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Choose Material">Choose Material</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><select name="os1">
                                     <option value="Metal">Metal </option>
                                     <option value="Acrylic">Acrylic </option>
                                     <option value="Canvas">Canvas </option>
                                    </select> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Choose Mount">Choose Mount</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><select name="os2">
                                     <option value="Mount 1">Mount 1 </option>
                                     <option value="Mount 2">Mount 2 </option>
                                     <option value="Mount 3">Mount 3 </option>
                                    </select> </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
              <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
              <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
          </center>
          <div class="imgBtns">
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('myImg2').src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0019-Recovered.jpg'"><img class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 img-responsive" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0019-Recovered.jpg' /></a>
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('myImg2').src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0073-Recovered.jpg'"><img class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 img-responsive" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0073-Recovered.jpg' /></a>
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('myImg2').src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0073-Recovered.jpg'"><img class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 img-responsive" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0073-Recovered.jpg' /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You simply write the HTML that you want at the bottom after the HTML that you want at the top...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The best way to align element is `Flexbox` [Here Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

*You can not use float to adjust vertical align.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
 <style> 
        #container{
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   background-color: pink;
  } 
  
  #first{
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 30vw;  
  }
  
  #other{
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 70vw;
   background: antiquewhite;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  #div1{
   display: flex;
   align-self: flex-start;  
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: aquamarine;   
  }
  
  #div2{
   background-color: aquamarine;
   align-self: flex-end;  
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   height: 50px;   
  }
 </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
                <div id="first">first</div>
                <div id="other">
                  <div id="div1">div1</div>
                  <div id="div2">div2</div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your modal has `position:relative`, just add following to the div you want to float down:

```
.divThatNeedsToBeFloatedDown {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

or, respectively:

```
.divThatNeedsToBeFloateUp {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this, and it works, except for the fact that my div that I float down has floated to the left and overlapped my first div in my modal, if this makes sense.

Comment: My first div takes up the first 6 columns and fills the height of the the section, and id like my next two divs to be stacked to the right of that div. So the third div, the one we are talking about, would go underneath the PayPal button, which is the second div. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: sorry, really not getting how you want it. Could you draw this or explain again? thanks)

Comment: div 3 is the one I am struggling with, it is currently being pulled up to div 2, and i'd like it to stick to the bottom of the container. Check my original post, I added a drawing.